# Running rake tasks on Win 10 in VSCode Terminal adds a default -w flag

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rake, minitest

I'm not completely sure how this happened or how to change the settings, but now when I run

> `rake <name_of_task>`

The executable shows this:

> `C:/Ruby30-x64/bin/ruby.exe -w -I"lib" C:/Ruby30-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb "<the dir of the test and filename>"`

...which then seems to give Ruby.exe the command flag `-w`, which shows code formatting warnings as STDout in the Terminal, such as:

> `warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'def' at 8`

That's all fine because it's STDout, so it's not writing to our logs, but it makes debugging in VScode terminal kind of insane because there are 100's of these warnings now.

The weirder part is that when my coworkers run this same code, they're getting the same output now. I'm not sure how that's even possible unless there's a bug in Rake?

Another thing is that when you run a straight ruby test (using minitest), it doesn't show this output at all. So has anyone else seen this using `rake-13.0.3` gem?

Answer (score 0):

Alright - figured it out.

`rake` defaults `warning` to `true`, which adds a `-w` flag to the Ruby executable.

Example of how to fix:

```
Rake::TestTask.new("<task_name>") do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList["test/<file.rb>"]
  t.warning = false   <-- must be false to remove -w flag
end
```